# Resource management in F#

Tags: f#

I know I need to use `use` keywork to dispose resouce:

```
use db = new dbml.MobileDataContext(connectionString)
for rows in db.Item do 
....
```

But I want to create the function which returns db connection:

```
let getConnection(connectionString) =
   use db = new dbml.MobileDataContext(connectionString)
   db.ExecuteCommand(....) |> ignore
   db
```

and use this function in my code:

```
use db = getConnection(connectionString)      
for rows in db.Item do 
....
```

Do I need to use `use`-keyword in such case two times: in the function and in the function call ?

Comment: The answer from @Tarmil is correct, but if you want, you can call `.Dispose()` explicitly on the connection.

Comment: In that case, `use` must *not* be used for it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only use `use` in the outer function. If you use it inside `getConnection`, then your context will be disposed upon returning from `getConnection`, and so it will be already disposed in the outer function when you want to use it. As a general rule, if you dispose a value in a function then you must not return it.

Answer (score 6):

@Tarmil has the right answer but I also wanted to point out a more idiomatic alternative to returning an already-open connection.

You could instead define a `withConnection` higher order function that takes a function as its parameter. The function you pass in would accept an open connection and return whatever results it wanted, letting `withConnection` handle the disposal of the connection. Here's the boilerplate:

```fsharp
let withConnection f =
    use db = new dbml.MobileDataContext(connectionString)
    db.ExecuteCommand(....) |> ignore
    f db
```

You could then use it like this without having to worry about closing the connection from elsewhere in the code:

```fsharp
let users = withConnection (fun conn -> conn.ExecuteQuery(...))
```